# TFS and VSTS - on premise and cloud source code

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Our product has offerings for on premise and cloud solutions. Recently we have migrated the source code from TFS to VSTS. Cloud solution is in VSTS version control, while the product's on-premise code is still in TFS. As we have to support both on prem and cloud solutions, what's the best practice for merging the required code between the version controls and for managing them? 
Or Is it a good idea to keep both the source code ( on prem and cloud) either in one version control - TFS /VSTS?

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Just because your application runs on-prem, there's no reason you have to maintain on-prem source control for it. The opposite is also true: just because you have a cloud-based application, there's no reason you have to use cloud-based source control for it.

Don't maintain two separate systems. There are no advantages and numerous downsides.

Either stick with on-prem TFS, or move everything to Azure DevOps. Personally, I'd move to Azure DevOps to avoid the burden of maintaining and upgrading infrastructure.